# Creating reports in Silverlight 4. (PDF/Word export) What are the main options?

Tags: silverlight, reporting-services, telerik

From my research it seems like the main option is to call up a HTML page from your Silverlight application and print from there..  So to use SSRS or Telerik Reporting for example.

Is there anyway to just print and export to PDF/Word from inside the Silverlight application  ?

What options can I look into ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to print directly from Silverlight 4.  You might create UserContols whose express purpose is to be a component that you use when generating Report pages.

Comment: but what about the need to export to PDF? Are there any non-web ways to do this directly from SL ?  I can't find any.

Comment: @punkouter:  Try web search for "Print to PDF driver" and "Silverlight PDF Generation" there are several solutions out there some open source some commercial.